# Does this video give a useful simplification of semiconductors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, semiclassical

Eugene Khutoryansky has a YouTube channel that is quite popular for its representations of physics concepts. This [particular video](https://youtu.be/hrpPKCDLRN0) discusses basic semiconductor theory in an easy to understand way, employing animated depictions of energy bands, donor states, interband transitions, depletion regions, holes, etc. Obviously, *any* visual representation of semiconductors will involve some simplifications/approximations, but I am curious to know to what extent this video accurately describes semiconductor theory. **What, if anything, should be changed to make it more accurate?** Can this be considered a useful teaching aid for a simplified introduction to semiconductors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video is surprisingly good.

I did have one objection. They try to push the "holes are 'just' missing electrons" model at 9:30 when they say "a hole moving to the left requires an electron moving to the right". This is overly simplistic and breaks down when you want to discuss the Hall effect (which is how we know there are both electrons and holes).

Holes actually act like a positive charge is moving, which regular electrons can't simulate. Hole movement isn't like a bubble moving through a tube of water. In a tube of water a bubble moves left when the water moves right. Hole movement is more like a box on a conveyor belt. The box represents a particular energy state that can be either filled or empty. But moves along the same path either way. If the box is filled it does not contribute to current, if it is empty it does contribute to current. To really explain what is going on requires a discussion of the energy-momentum relationship of the energy bands, which is above the level of the video. But I would caution against using the "holes are 'just' missing electrons' model. Holes are on equal footing with electrons as charge carriers in a semiconductor (both are Bloch states, what we call 'electrons' in semiconductors aren't 'normal' electrons either).

They had a bunch of animated 3D energy band diagrams, but never really explained what they were showing, and I don't believe they named the "conduction band" and "valence band", but I could have just missed it. That would benefit from more explanation.

Even ignoring that objection, this would be a good teaching aid as an introduction to semiconductors.